# Renegade, epitasis, and then what?

Tags: word, word-sequence

Complete this finite convoluted sequence of words

> renegade, epitasis, nihilist, etiolate, gallinae, ...

Comment: This was [automatically flagged as low-quality](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/47979). Silly bot :-)

Comment: Given that the problem was solved so fast It has got a point.  I probably should have given fewer words.

Comment: Actually the opposite, from the bot/system's point of view: it was flagged for being *too short*.

Comment: It was on -1, for no very obvious reason, when I saw it. I don't know whether the "low quality" metric takes early votes into account somehow. (I think exactly what it does is deliberately not disclosed.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The remaining words are

> ASIANISM, DISTASTE, ESTEEMED

because

> then the eight 8-letter words form a word-square (and I think this is the only continuation with that property).

Comment: You could also have R as last letter, but D is better.

Comment: Oh, I suppose you _could_, but that's a pretty poor sort of a word :-).